# Pusher inside a laravel project and jquery ?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, pusher

Here is the thing

first i have a laravel app that requires a real time chat application integrated inside .

i made the html structure so well ( could say like facebook )

a box that list all available users like this

[image]

after i click on any user it will pop up a chat box like these

[image]

okay sending messages using pusher and laravel echo  from single opened box to another one in another browser is working fine cause in each browser there is a single channel opened i named it send_message_( then i bind user id that i want to notify him ) that works fine  .

but : 
the problem is when i open more than one chat box  i that mean there as much as number of channels found in browser  when i hit send from any box  it will notify ( this user that i intend to send a message to him ) and also users that their boxes opened also which is very wrong  .

i initialize pusher in registering popup i don't know if this is right or not

here is the initialization code  :

```
function register_popup(box, name , auth_user , user_to )
    {





                Pusher.logToConsole = true;
                // then i will use pusher here  
                var pusher = new Pusher('2d203fcacc26d62ef49b', { 
                    cluster:'mt1'
                });


                // Subscribe to the channel we specified in our Laravel Event
                var channel = pusher.subscribe('send_message_'+ user_to );


                // Bind a function to a Event (the full Laravel class)
                channel.bind("App\\Events\\MessageWasRecieved" ,   function(response) {




                    // alert(response.message);


                    $('.ul_holder_'+user_to).html(); 
                    $('.ul_holder_'+user_to).append(

                        `

                            <li>
                                    <div class="_4dt ua1">
                                        <div class="user_image"> 
                                        <img  src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/users/`+response.image+`" class="img-circle" alt="">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="message_content"> 
                                            <span class="text">`+response.message+`</span>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                            </li>


                        `


                    ); 

                        // $('ul.ul_holder li:last').scrollTop(); 

                        var chatAudio = new Audio("{{ asset('sound/message.mp3') }}");
                        chatAudio.loop = false;
                        chatAudio.play();   



                });  





        for(var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++)
        {   
            //already registered. Bring it to front.
            if(box == popups[iii])
            {
                Array.remove(popups, iii);

                popups.unshift(box);

                calculate_popups();


                return;
            }
        } 


        var id = auth_user ; 
        var to_user = user_to ; 
        var token = $('input[name=_token]').val();  
        var lang = $('input[name=language]').val();  



                        // i shall do my ajax logic here 

                         $.ajax({

                             cache: false, 
                             dataType:'json', 
                             url : "check" ,
                             data: { _token:token ,  id:id  , to_user:to_user  },
                             method : 'GET',
                             beforeSend:function(){

                             }, 
                             success:function(data){


                                conversation = data.conversation_id ; 




                                var test = `
                                <div class="message_box" id='`+box+`'>

                                          <div class="message_head"> 
                                              <span class="message_user ">`+ name +`</span>


                                              <div class="close">
                                                 <a href="javascript:close_popup('`+box+`');"> × </a>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="wrapper">

                                          <div class="message_body" >
                                          <ul class='ul_holder_`+box+`' data-body=`+conversation+`>
                                          <button class='btn btn-rounded btn-default text-center old_history_btn' data-conversation-id='`+conversation+`' data-auth-user='`+auth_user+`'>load old history</button>
                                          </ul>
                                          </div>


                                              <div class="message_footer">

                                              <textarea name="" id="" class="message_input" data-auth-id='`+auth_user+`' data-to-user-id='`+user_to+`' data-conversation-id='`+conversation+`'   placeholder="write message"></textarea>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>

                                      </div>
                                `; 


                                document.getElementsByClassName("other_area")[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("other_area")[0].innerHTML + test;  

                                popups.unshift(box);




                                calculate_popups();

                             },





                        });
                        return false ; 









    }
```

if i want to restrict this i have an event of keydown that will send  post ajax request to insert my message in database then return a json response when i tried to initialize pusher in success function it doesn't work for first time 
then if i hit  send again it sends successfully ,but i find my self entering a loop of repeating messages

here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){





        $(document).on('keydown' , '.message_input', function(e){


            var token = $('input[name=_token]').val(); 
            var msg  = $(this).val(); 
            var element = $(this) ; 



            var ul = element.parent().parent().find('ul'); 




            var authenticated_user_id = $(this).attr('data-auth-id'); 
            var user_id = $(this).attr('data-to-user-id'); 
            var conversation_id = $(this).attr('data-conversation-id'); 







            if(!msg == '' && e.keyCode == 13  && !e.shiftKey){






                                $.ajax({

                                    cache: false, 
                                    dataType:'json', 
                                    url : '{{ url("$lang/post_message")}}' ,
                                    data: {   
                                            msg:msg  , authenticated_user_id:authenticated_user_id  , user_id:user_id , conversation_id: conversation_id , _token:token
                                    },
                                    method : 'POST',

                                    success:function(data){






                                        if(data.status == "success"){




                                            var message = data.message  ; 

                                           ul.append(

                                                `

                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="_4dme ua1">
                                                            <div class="message_content_me"> 
                                                                <span class="text">`+message+`</span>

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>


                                                `


                                            );




                                            element.val('');



                                                var sendingMessage = new Audio("{{ asset('sound/sending_message.mp3') }}");
                                                    sendingMessage.loop = false;
                                                    sendingMessage.play();









                                        }else{


                                            console.log('catch error');
                                        }








                                    }
                                });


                                return false ;    




            } 









        });

    });
```

i hope i had described my problem correct , that's what is pending so that i could finish the full chat system

thanks

Comment: Check this out https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily an answer to your question specifically, but you might want to consider a new product more suited to your specific needs that works similarly to Pusher in a lot of ways. https://pusher.com/chatkit